# Hide data point on x axis at location "0" in win chart controls

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, charts, asp.net-charts

I am plotting graph as shown in the image below. On x axis i dont have location "0", can i hide that point. The values on x axis vary from -35 to 35 where 0 is not present. The x axis values are just numbers.

[image]

Comment: You have repeatedly stated that you want to remove a datapoint. What you actualy mean is not a datapoint but a label!

Comment: Actually I made a mistake I writing the question.

Comment: To improve the SO archive, please edit and corrct the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** freely change the text of the axis labels nor skip any of them nor make them transparent selectively.

But there are two options:

- You can replace the axis labels by `CustomLabels`. This means you need to create and add them all, each with two numbers which give a `FromPosition` and a `ToPosition`, i.e. a range inside of which the `CustomLabel` shall be centered.

Often you can cheat and use an actual x-value and simply subtract / add a small value; not too small so that the label still fits in.

If you have explicitly set the axis `Interval` (as you seem to have done) `1/2` or `1/3` of that would be good offsets; or if you also have set `Minumum` and `Maximum` you can calculate the range properly in loop, see below!

- **But in your case** the solution is **much simpler**: you can format the axis label like this:

---

```
Axis ax = yourChartArea.AxisX;
ax.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "#";
```

Of course this only work because the value you want to hide is `0`, which the number format can suppress.

---

The first option, of course is much more powerful. So let's look at an example for this option as well:

```
double delta = ax.Interval / 3d;
for (double x = ax.Minimum; x <= ax.Maximum; x+=ax.Interval)
{
    CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
    cl.ToPosition = x + delta;
    cl.FromPosition = x - delta;
    cl.Text =  x.ToString();  // pick your text/format!
    if (x != 0) ax.CustomLabels.Add(cl);
}
```

The result looks the same for both methods:

[image]

Comment: I have come up with solution of plotting two chart areas side by side. In this way I can eliminate 0 label.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are databinding X and Y axis using two arrays, find the location within the X axis array where the value for zero should be and add the X and Y axis values as follows:

```
xaxisarray(z) = 0.0        'In case of a double type array
yaxisarray(z) = Double.NaN 'Add a value that is not a number
```

Also make sure to resize the X and Y axis array before adding the above values, and move the values one step as shown below:

```
System.Array.Resize(Of Double)(xaxisarray, xaxisarray.Length + 1)
System.Array.Resize(Of Double)(yaxisarray, yaxisarray.Length + 1)
For i As Integer = xaxisarray.Length - 1 To z + 1 Step -1
    xaxisarray(i) = xaxisarray(i - 1)
    yaxisarray(i) = yaxisarray(i - 1)
Next
```

Comment: Actually i am not adding any point in the series that has 0 as x value.

Comment: If you use line or fastline to plot, it just connect two datapoints. Even though, there are no values at x-axis value (0), it just connected x axis values at -1 and +1, which seems like a plot value at 0. You could either change the chart type to Point type or Else add a marker for each data point that is being added.